# In Django is it possible to add url directory instead of url file

Tags: python, django, django-urls

normally we do like

```
path("", include("app.urls"), name="") # urls is urls.py
```

but is it possible to add a directory not the urls.py file?

```
path("", include("app.folder"), name="") # inside the folder urls.py file lives
```

Comment: in general, it is `path.to.directory.file_containing_patterns`, which means `app.folder.urls` would work

Comment: yes, but can it be done without giving the `file_containing_patterns`

Answer (score 0):

solved by adding patterns in `__init__.py` inside the directory

```
path("", include("app.folder"), name="")

# folder/__init__.py
path("/users", include("api.urls.users")),

# folder/users.py
path("", app.views, name=""),
```